# How to position two widget in a same Row?

Tags: flutter

I have a Country code(DropdownMenu) and phone (TextFormField), how can I put them in same level? 
I've tried Align widget.

```
Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: DropdownButtonFormField(
                      value: _selectedCountryCode ?? 'TR',
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedCountryCode = value;
                        });
                      },
                      items: countryCodes,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 4,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Phone"),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Don't forget to add the code of your widget.

Comment: in `Row()` widget you can use `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline`

Comment: @danish-khan-I crossAxisAlignment !=
I/flutter ( 2417): CrossAxisAlignment.baseline || textBaseline != null': is not true.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Thanks to @danish-khan-I, I solved using `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline`. But you also have to provide `textBaseline` otherwise it gives an exception.

So in my row I've used:

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline
textBaseline: TextBaseline.ideographic,
```

Comment: Thanks for the `textBaseline` tip