# What does CrossAxisAlignment.baseline, in Column

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, flutter-column

I have a question, I want to know what is the functionality of `CrossAxisAlignment.baseline` when we use **Column** in Flutter , nothing happen when I used this attribute
can any one help me to figure out what is job.
And I have to use `textBaseline: TextBaseline` attribute to use `CrossAxisAlignment.baseline`

Here is a Sample code I used

```
 return Container(
  width: 200,
  color: Colors.pink[200],
  child: Column(
    textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
   // mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      Text('text'),
      Text('text2'),
      Container(
        color: Colors.yellow,
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.pink,
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
      ),
      Container(
        color: Colors.indigo,
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629733/how-to-position-two-widget-in-a-same-row/56629987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually using baseline in `Column` is of no use but while using it in a `Row`.
**Note:** If you use crossAxisAlignment.baseline without defining textBaseLine the app will encounter an error [Check Image for more simplified understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zoyq.png)

```
Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
      textBaseline: TextBaseline.alphabetic,
      children: [
        Text('50',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 50, decoration: TextDecoration.underline,  decorationColor: Colors.green)),
        Text('KG',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20, decoration: TextDecoration.underline, decorationColor: Colors.green)),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It makes clear now